# How would a range work if the starting point and ending points are the same in Python

Tags: python, range

I am relatively new to coding and saw this question on a video.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKZXL.jpg)

Like for the

```
for i in range(2, num):
```

line I understand how it would work when plugging in a number 3 or greater for the variable `num` but I do not understand how it would work if it were to be 2.

The code checks if it is a prime number, so if I plug in 2 it would be:

```
for i in range (2,num-1):
```

which is

```
for i in range (2,1):
```

How would the code still run?

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use [code formatting](/editing-help#code). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: What do you mean by `num-1`? That's not in the attached code. Do you mean that the interval becomes *[2, 1]*? (equivalent to *[2, 2) ∈ ℤ*)

Answer (score 1):

A `range(start, stop)` is a half open interval from `start` to but exluding `stop`.  See [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) for the details.  The range may be empty as would be the case for your example of `range(2,1)`, note, however there is also a `step` argument if you want the range to down instead of up `range(2, 1, -1)` which in this case would evaluate to `2`.

Answer (score 0):

The range will be empty and it will simply skip the for loop.

Not much unlike this:

```
empty_list = []
for item in empty_list:
   print("I love pumpkin") # will never run
```